# catch malformed URI errors thrown by vite in nuxt3

Tags: vite, nuxt3

If I navigate to `siteUrl/%91` for instance, I will get an error from server side:

```
Internal server error: URI malformed 
at decodeURI (<anonymous>)
at viteTransformMiddleware
```

Is there any way to catch this particular error? I'd like to redirect user to our 404 page instead.

I tried creating a middleware to check if the `route` could be decoded before vite attempts to do it and do a redirect but it did not work.

I also attempted all error handling on https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/error-handling but none seems to catch this particular error.